# Query AWS CloudFront metric with boto3 without result

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

given the following query:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cw = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')
    response = cw.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace='AWS/CloudFront',
        MetricName='Requests',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'Region',
                'Value': 'Global'
            },
            {
                'Name': 'DistributionId',
                'Value': '...'
            }
        ],
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=16),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period=300,
        Statistics=[
            'Sum'
        ],
        Unit='Seconds'
    )
```

I want to query the number of requests from CloudWatch but the result is empty:

```
{
"Label": "Requests",
"Datapoints": [],
"ResponseMetadata": {
"RequestId": "...",
"HTTPStatusCode": 200,
"HTTPHeaders": {
"x-amzn-requestid": "...",
"content-type": "text/xml",
"content-length": "331",
"date": "..."
},
"RetryAttempts": 0
}
}
```

The query is executed from AWS Lambda function, and it seems, that the permissions are set correctly